# how to place ejs <%= value %> between <>?

Tags: ejs

Essentially I am trying to do this:

```
To: <%= userName %> <<%= userEmail%>>
```

But the double brackets seem to make "userEmail" return nothing.

Answer: User @haxxxton had the correct answer of

```
To: <%= userName %> &lt;<%= userEmail%>&gt;
```

Comment: looks fine to me; maybe `userEmail` is undefined

Comment: That what I thought but without the extra brackets it renders just fine.

Comment: could also be its trying to create an html element out of your value due to the angle brackets.. try replacing them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: Seems to work if I put spaces between the brackets `< <%=userEmail%> >`

Comment: sounds like it was trying to turn it into an html element